# Which version of Kali Linux am I using?

Tags: kali-linux, software-updates

After getting a request to install OS updates I waited almost 12 hours, which after being done I ran `grep Version /etc/os-release`. It says version 2018.4 but, when I run `uname -a` and `uname -r` both say 4.17.0. So shouldn't it say 4.18.0? I also had a folder or directory called `kali live` and now it is gone.

Comment: Jesus guys not every post is a duplicate of why is Kali so hard to set up

Answer (score 8):

`/etc/os-release` shows information about the currently installed operating system. 2018.4 is the release you’re running of whatever distribution you’re using.

`uname` shows information about the *running* kernel. 4.17.0 is the (base) version of the running kernel. You might have 4.18 installed too, but until you reboot, it won’t be the running kernel.

Comment: I did reboot twice nothing changed plus when i right click on desktop the create new folder option is gone